# IBM mobile first platform V7.0.0 - disable Application console authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

We want to use IBM MFP app store to be used by our users, we are trying to put MFP App store behind our Portal which has Authentication. Hence we would like to just publish download of App .../installer.html link in our portal, but do not want OOTB authentication of MFP. how to disable this ? just like no authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication to the Application Center console cannot be disabled at all. It is required as it needs also authorization based on Java EE roles and the console invokes also secured REST services.
But as SSO is required if the user is already connected (whether on another application or with a Web SSO system), it will be automatically connected to the AppCenter console.

Same when installing apps on the mobile from the Application Center client. The client invokes the REST services that are secured with basic authentication.

Comment: Thank you Arjan, can we disable both authentication and authorization as I want my users have internal authorization within the Portal, How to enable SSO is also not clear as we use Siteminder for Authentication.I am only disabling App download, not the Runtime and Analytics Authentication. can we disable authentication and Authorization for App download feature only.